# Android: Reading from SQLite Database at runtime

Tags: android, runtime-error, android-sqlite, sqlite

So I have made a database to use in my Android app. What I am trying to do is simple, just read from my database and display the data in a TextView, here is the DataBaseHelper class

```
    package com.tix.activity;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.tix.activity/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "tix";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
    private final Context myContext;

    public DatabaseHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
    }else{
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try{
            copyDataBase();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying Database");
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }catch(SQLiteException e){

    }
    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer,0,length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close(){
    if(myDatabase != null)
        myDatabase.close();
    super.close();

}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public Cursor data(){
    Cursor c;
    c = myDatabase.query(DB_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    return c;
}
}
```

And this is my MainActivity class

```
package com.tix.activity;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Cursor cur;
TextView tv;
Button next, prev;
DatabaseHelper dbh;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nbtn);
        prev = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pbtn);

        dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        try {
            dbh.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        dbh.openDataBase();
        cur = dbh.data();
        cur.moveToFirst();
        tv.setText(cur.getString(1));

        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(cur.isLast())
                {
                    cur.moveToFirst();
                    tv.setText(""+cur.getString(1));
                }
                else
                {
                    cur.moveToNext();
                    tv.setText(""+cur.getString(1));

                }
            }
        });
        prev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(cur.isFirst()){
                cur.moveToLast();
                tv.setText(""+cur.getString(1));
            }
            else
            {
                cur.moveToPrevious();
                tv.setText(""+cur.getString(1));
            }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

But, everytime I run the app in emulator it just crashes. But if I put in 
            tv.setText(cur.getString(0));
instead of
            tv.setText(cur.getString(1));

then I get textview to display 'en_US' (which I don't really want to display, probably its from locale) and upon pressing either of the buttons the app crashes.

Here is the error that I get on LogCat,

```
07-03 16:37:45.120: E/CursorWindow(1912): Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 1 columns.
07-03 16:37:45.160: D/AndroidRuntime(1912): Shutting down VM
07-03 16:37:45.160: W/dalvikvm(1912): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
07-03 16:37:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1912): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 16:37:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1912): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
07-03 16:37:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
07-03 16:37:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
07-03 16:37:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
07-03 16:37:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at com.tix.activity.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:65)
07-03 16:37:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
07-03 16:37:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
07-03 16:37:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-03 16:37:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-03 16:37:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-03 16:37:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
07-03 16:37:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 16:37:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-03 16:37:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-03 16:37:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-03 16:37:45.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1912):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-03 16:39:01.480: I/Process(1912): Sending signal. PID: 1912 SIG: 9
07-03 16:39:30.201: W/Trace(1966): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-03 16:39:30.201: W/Trace(1966): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-03 16:39:30.631: W/Trace(1966): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-03 16:39:30.631: W/Trace(1966): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
07-03 16:39:31.522: E/CursorWindow(1966): Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 1 columns.
07-03 16:39:31.531: D/AndroidRuntime(1966): Shutting down VM
07-03 16:39:31.531: W/dalvikvm(1966): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tix.activity/com.tix.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at com.tix.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-03 16:39:31.582: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     ... 11 more
```

My xml is as follows, this doesn't matter, anyway,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="Back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/pbtn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pbtn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:text="Next" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pbtn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="141dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I made the database using SQLite Database Browser, but it contains a table called android_metadata with locale (text) field with value as 'en_US' and the other table is 'tix' with primary field as '_id' and the other field as 'jokes'. That is all.

Could anyone point out what is wrong? And how do I rectify it? I definitely need help with this, because this is my first shot at database :/

Comment: Please consider using `SQLiteAssetHelper` to handle setting up a pre-packaged database: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: I don't know much, but from what I read, it pretty much does the same thing. And as for trying, I just did now, didn't help, get the exact same error messages. Thanks though.

Comment: Please help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728808/android-reading-stored-sqlite-database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just putting a cursor into a TextView does not work. You need to fetch the content first.

you coukd try it like this in your DB class:

```
public String data(){
    Cursor c;
    String result;


     c = myDatabase.query(DB_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);

        try {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    result = cursor.getString(0);
                }
                result = c.getString(0);
            } finally {
                c.close();
            }

    return result;
}
```

and in your TextView:

```
tv.setText(dbh.data());
```

Or something like that

Not the best way but should work

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, it doesn't work. I believe it has to do with column or row index maybe? I have 2 tables in my database, android_metadata and tix, how do I select tix table from database though? I have googled a lot, haven't found an  explanation to help me with this. I clearly don't have any idea.

Comment: You select the database in the query. DB_NAME is your Table.

Comment: Thank you, now I can access my db partially. Say my db is, 
`|--------------------------|`
`| _id    |   jokes         |
|--------------------------|
|  1     |   jokeA         |
|  2     |   jokeB         |
|--------------------------|`

now I get,

output as "1" when `getString(0)` and jokeA if `getString(1)`, how do I get jokeB? Any other integer value crashes the application!

Comment: I just realised you have to specify the other statements. I'll add another answer later today. I'm busy right now :) Hang in there :) You could read the documentation for the query in the meanwhile :)

Comment: Okay, just alter the query to what you need it to do http://goo.gl/0jg3k
Set variables which you pass from your activity into the query so you can qery for pretty much any data in your db

Comment: Thank you for puttin up with me, I'll let you know after a while if this works, hope it will. :)